# Сохранение и получение значений в классе-наследнике от AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

Изучаю `AspNetCore.Identity` в `MVC` с целью подключения авторизации и аутентификации на создаваемом сайте. Вот, что у меня есть: Создал класс `SiteUser` и унаследовался от `IndetityUser`. Про методы `SetLastLoginDate()` и `GetLastLoginDate()` - по ходу вопроса. Пока не обращайте внимания.

```
public class SiteUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public GenderType? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Locale { get; set; } = "en-us";
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime? ConfirmDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }

        public void SetLastLoginDate(DateTime last)
        {
            LastLoginDate = last;
        }

        public DateTime? GetLastLoginDate()
        {
            return LastLoginDate;
        }
    }
```

В `Startup.cs` подключил `SiteUser` вместо `IdentityUser`:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup( IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Configuration.Bind("Database", new SiteConfiguration());

            services.AddDbContext<SiteDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(SiteConfiguration.ConnectionString));

            services.AddIdentity<SiteUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SiteDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Site.Cookie";
                options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/accessdenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                config.AddPolicy("Registered", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole("Registered"));
                config.AddPolicy("Confirmed", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole("Confirmed"));
                config.AddPolicy("Administrator", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole("Administrator"));
            });

            services.AddMailKit(configuration => 
                configuration.UseMailKit(Configuration.GetSection("EMail").Get<MailKitOptions>()));

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

            services.AddSession();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));
        }
    }
```

Создал контроллер `AccountController.cs`, в котором создал 2 action `Login()` с разными сигнатурами. (Внимание - в этом куске кода кроются попытки решить вопрос - выделены комментированием кода):

```
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<SiteUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<SiteUser> signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailService emailService;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<SiteUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<SiteUser> signInManager,
            IEmailService emailService
            )
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
            this.emailService = emailService;
        }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index() => RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).CutController());

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult AccessDenied() => RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).CutController());

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, System.Uri returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SiteUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                bool isEmailConfirmed = await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (isEmailConfirmed)
                {
                    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        // собственно, вот первая попытка задать значение в поле LastLginDate
                        user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Utc.Now;
                        // но она не работает - данные в БД не сохраняются.

                        // а вот вторая попытка, ради которой и были созданы методы SetLoginDate() и GetLastLoginDate()
                        DateTime? lastLogin = user.GetLastLoginDate();
                        user.SetLastLoginDate(DateTime.UtcNow);
                        // но и этот вариант не срабатывает

                        if(returnUrl != null)
                        {
                           // ...
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что получают данные из БД в виде `экземпляра класса` `SiteUser` и вношу изменения не в БД, а в экземпляр класса, но  именно в этом у меня вопрос - как зафиксировать изменения в экземпляре класса, чтобы они отразились в БД.

P.S.: Аутентификация и авторизация проходит нормально - пользователь может и входит на сайт под своей учетной записью и выходит из неё. Единственное, что еще мне не нравится - вместо одного экземпляра `Cookie` создаются дополнительно еще 2: `Site.Cookie` (это то, что я создал) и `.AspNetCore.AntiForgery` вместе с `.AspNetCore.Session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После всех изменений, с заданием новых значений у пользователя, необходимо вызвать UserManager.Update(user) для их сохранения.

Comment: Большое! Человеческое! Спасибо! Это именно то знание, которого мне не хватало!